# If/ Elses statement not executing properly

Tags: python-3.x, if-statement

I've altered the if/else statements several times and either **only** the if statement will be executed even if it's not true or **only** the else statement will be executed even if it's not true.

```
def interview():
""" NoneType -> NoneType
Interview the user. """
name = input("What is your name?")
unit = input("What is you preferred choice of unit - standard or imperial?")
weight = float(input("What is your weight?"))
height = float(input("What is your height?"))
a = float(bmi_std(weight, height))
b = float(bmi_std_prime(weight, height))
c = float(bmi_imp(weight, height))
d = float(bmi_imp_prime(weight, height))
e = str(category(weight, height, 's'))
f = str(category(weight, height, 'i'))

print("So," + name + ", your preferred unit is" + unit + ".")
print("Your weight", weight)
print("Your height", height)
if str(unit == 'imperial'):
    print("BMI = " + str(c) + " and your BMI prime = " + str(d))
    print("Category = " + f)
else:
    print("BMI = " + str(a) + " and your BMI prime = " + str(b))
    print("Category = " + e)
```

This is just part of my code. Is there something wrong in the way its written because it looks fine to me. I'm only an intro to programming.

Answer (score 2):

I can see an issue right away

`if str(unit == 'imperial'):` should be `if str(unit) == 'imperial':`

Comment: I just tried that but now it's only executing the else statement, despite the else statement being false. So, sam, your preferred unit is imperial.
Your weight 140.0
Your height 64.0
BMI = 0.0341796875 and your BMI prime = 0.0013671875
Category = Severely underweight

Comment: Well, aside from the issue with a typo (do you really want to make someone type out "imperial"?), there's also a problem if the wrong case is used, if there's leading/trailing whitespace, etc, etc... Abstract your problem. Create a boolean variable and use that.... `isImperial = true   ...   if isImperial:`. Then all you have to do is set the boolean correctly.